# preserve public folder after deployment with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I have a folder `public/recipes` with recipes inside of this folder.

However after deployment via `remote_cache` this folder and recipes are removed/deleted.

I do not want that capistrano remove/delete this folder and these recipes.

How I can get it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Capistrano 3 then just specify `public/recipes` directory in `linked_dirs` variable:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/uploads public/recipes}
```

It will set link between your directory and `shared/public/recipes`.

For Capistrano 2 you should set link "manually" in deploy.rb use `ln` command i.e. use something like this:

```
task :configure_symlinks, :roles => :web do
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/public/recipes #{current_release}/public/recipes"
end

after "deploy:update_code", "configure_symlinks"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a symlink, you will probably need something like https://github.com/capistrano/copy-files.

However, I highly recommend that you use linked dirs as ethyl.bradtke suggests. That is the best way to handle this.